# Kindle Fire's actual name on the ADB Devices List Not user-friendly

Tags: adb

When I connect my Kindle Fire and give the "adb devices" command this is what pans out:

```
aneesh@nb-14:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
D026A0A0305501NC        device
```

If there is no other USB device online, I can get away by simply typing `adb -d` followed by the command, as say developer.android.com, or if there is no other device online, no issues at all!

If there is more than one USB device online, then I have to type the name to uniquely specify the device to operate on. The name is some combination of upper-case characters and digits as seen above. Can anything be done to make it name the Kindle Fire in a more user-friendly manner, the way it names emulators?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is really your question? You want to send commands to more than one device?

Comment: The `adb devices` command lists all attached devices together with their *serial number* IMHO (or how else would you know what to specify with the `-s` parameter if you have multiple devices attached) -- so sorry, but a serial number is not friendly (also not to the user).

Comment: I think the only reason you think this is not user friendly is because you are unaware of tab completion :) It was quite the discovery when I came upon it the first time: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What makes this easy is using tab-completion to complete the device ID. Type

```
adb -s D0
```

and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. The plugin in your shell will run `adb devices` to find the full device ID and complete it on the command line for you. You can then type in the rest of the command.

`adb` is a tool for developers, and even developers don't usually run it by hand from the command-line: both the main Android development environments (Eclipse-based and IntelliJ IDEA-based) have GUI wrappers. There's not really a need for it to be any more user-friendly than it is.

Comment: For some programs, such as `screen` in a linux environment, auto completion is done in the software as well. Could be worth trying if `adb -s D` works, assuming there is only one device beginning with `D`.